# What does the FOR keyword do in this SQL Server ALTER TABLE clause?

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I'm not sure what FOR is doing in this SQL Server snippet.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] 
    ADD DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[TableName_Seq]) FOR [TableName_Key]
```

When I try to google for FOR clause the only meaningful result I got was [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but I don't think it's relevant

Comment: [NEXT VALUE FOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: [ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL) - Examples: Adding Columns and Constraints - D. Adding a DEFAULT constraint to an existing column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-adding-a-default-constraint-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: There are **two** `FOR` - which one is the one that's unclear to you??

Comment: Both, to be honest

Answer (score 3):

`FOR` is a keyword of the [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql) function. It is used to return the next value from the specified sequence object.

`FOR` is also a keyword of the [`DEFAULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql) constraint clause, specifying the target column name of the constraint.

In the context of the DDL in your question, the function result is the default value automatically assign the value when a value is not explicitly specified in `INSERT` statements.

BTW, it's a best practice to name constraints rather than relying on auto-generated names. This makes subsequent schema modifications easier.

Comment: True - **if** that's the `FOR` he's asking about - there are two `FOR` in that statement, though ....

Comment: Good point @marc_s, added that to my answer.

Comment: Another way of putting it is it's just one of those unnecessary and ambiguous (context-dependent) words that SQL loves, like `insert INTO` `fetch NEXT ... ONLY` `left OUTER join`

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface.

Answer (score 1):

`FOR` by itself has no specific meaning, it depends on context.

In this case, there are 2 usages of `FOR`:

- [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, which is used to generate the next value from a sequence.
- [`ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD [table_constraint]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax-for-disk-based-tables), where [`table_constraint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is of the form `DEFAULT constant_expression FOR column`. So it's adding a default constraint for the `TableName_Key` column, and the value for that default constraint is coming from the `TableName_Seq` sequence.